# Should there be a tag for each country?

Tags: discussion, tagging

On the private beta so far users have been adding new tags for each country being referred to. (I created 'Philippines' for [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/480/visa-on-arrival-scheme-in-philippines), for instance.) Should there be a tag for each country? I'd say yes...but this also means having [around 200 tags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states) just for countries.

Comment: If you can foresee specific problems with having large numbers of tags I think those would make more interesting meta posts of their own.

Comment: @hippietrail: What I meant is, since we need a tag for each country - and new tags can be created without moderator intervention during private beta - should they be created now before the public beta starts?

Comment: @Ankur: Oh I think that could be an option at least until we get to the edge-case countries like protectorates and principalities or countries with controversial or ambiguous names like Macedonia.

Comment: @Dori: [tag:burma] looks pretty good. Maybe we should add they speak their own language written in their own alphabet, maybe main language(s) should be on each country. The hard bit is choosing what to put in the limited excerpt and what to leave for the full tag wiki.

Comment: @Dori: For tags like 'Burma', should we use the old name or the new official name 'Myanmar'? Otherwise, that's like creating a tag 'Peking' for Beijing.

Comment: @Dori: Yes, I did. I'm pointing this out because its an archaic term that some people in the region take might take offence to, and this is something that should be kept in mind for a site like Travel SE with international scope. It's like using 'Bombay' or 'Peking' - no big deal for an outsider, but sometimes interpreted as 'Westerners' sticking to their 'colonial' mindset in trying to impose a name that locals 'rejected'. (Personally, I don't care but some do.) Is it not, therefore, just better to stick to the official name in these situations?

Comment: @Dori: FWIW, the travel communities usually call a place by its official name. [Lonely Planet](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/myanmar-burma), [Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Talk:Myanmar#Myanmar_vs._Burma) - use 'Myanmar' as the primary name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there should. There is nothing that can hurt the system by having lots of tags. There will also be many tags for cities and regions.

Comment: Agreed, I think it is required.